# Global exception handler not redirect error page when partial view return

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my controller

```
public IActionResult Privacy(int? id)
        {
            if(id.HasValue)
                throw new Exception("privacy page exception");

            return View();  ///working- redirected to Error view
        }


  [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SearchCustomerPartial([FromQuery] CustomerSearch searchModel)
        {
            
            try { 
             var result = await _customerapiService.SearchCustomer(searchModel);

            return PartialView("_CustomerList", result.Data);
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");   ---Not working it remains in same controller
        }
        }
```

Global exception handler

```
  public static void UseGlobalExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app
                                                    , ILogger logger
                                                    , string errorPagePath
                                                    , bool respondWithJsonErrorDetails = false)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
            {
                appBuilder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    //============================================================
                    //Log Exception
                    //============================================================
                    var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;

                    string errorDetails = $@"{exception.Message}
                                             {Environment.NewLine}
                                             {exception.StackTrace}";

                    int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                    context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
                 
                        //Check status code, if different  redirect error page
                        context.Response.Redirect(errorPagePath); --- Redirect code

                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    
                });
            });
        }
```

Problem:

I  have 2 Methods Privacy() and SearchCustomerPartial() in controller.

My global exception handler working fine for Privacy it redirect to Error view when error.

But not not working for SearchCustomerPartial()   (returns partial view)

if any exceptions   in the  SearchCustomerPartial()   not redirected to Error view  and showing Error in same page and overlap.

Below is the Error page

[image: SearchCustomerPartial]

How to redirect to Error page in the partial view returns in the controller .. Am using Asp.net core 3.1

Kindly suggest..

EDIT:

My javascript Code

```
    fetch(url + "?" + o)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(html => {
                debugger
                // console.log(html);
                document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                             debugger
                          console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err)
                          document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = "";
                         });
```

Server returns 500 But it not coming under Catch in javscript..Kindly suggest

if Bad Request come from server how to handle in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if any exceptions in the SearchCustomerPartial() not redirected to Error view and showing Error in same page and overlap.

Based on your code and requirement, you can try to modify the code like below.

```
fetch(url + "?" + o)
        .then(function (response) {
            //check if it is redirected to custom error page
            if (response.redirected && response.url.indexOf("/Home/Error1")>0) {
                response.text().then(function (html) {
                    document.write(html);
                });
            } else {
                response.text().then(function (html) {
                    document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
                });
            }
        })
```

Comment: in my server server send 500 status but when i checking in browser Status with 200   why getting status with Ok ,,,can pls just explain i am new javascript..